# DOM XML Parser Example

Tags: java, xml

I have this XML file.I just parse this XML file.This example shows how to get the node by “name”, and display the value.How to show all records from database?

```
<data399173_eff_sor>
<record>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <item_no>1.0</item_no>
    <description>Hack off tiles and make good walls</description>
    <price>100</price>
    <base_qty>50</base_qty>
    <var_qty>20</var_qty>
    <base_price_>5000</base_price_>   
</record>
<record>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <item_no>1.03</item_no>
    <description>Test</description>
    <price>45</price>
    <base_qty>100</base_qty>
    <var_qty>4500</var_qty>
    <base_price_>0</base_price_>
</record>
</data399173_eff_sor>
```

and so on

Java code

```
   File fXmlFile = new File("D:/formdata.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("record");

    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            System.out.println("Item No : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("item_no").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Description : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("price : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("base qty : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("base_qty").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Var qty : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("var_qty").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Base price : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("base_price_").item(0).getTextContent());                

        }
```

In this its just show first record.i want to display all records in the data base

Comment: I edited my XML File.Now this is original file which i downloaded from the server

Answer (score 9):

The xml is not valid. (You can validate your xml online: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)

You can try with this xml

```
<records>
 <record>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <item_no>1.0</item_no>
  <description>Hack off tiles and make good walls</description>
  <price>100</price>
  <base_qty>50</base_qty>
  <var_qty>20</var_qty>
  <base_price_>5000</base_price_>   
 </record>
 <record>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <item_no>1.03</item_no>
  <description>Test</description>
  <price>45</price>
  <base_qty>100</base_qty>
  <var_qty>4500</var_qty>
  <base_price_>0</base_price_>
 </record>
</records>
```

and keep your code

```
package test;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class TestXml{ 
 public static void main (String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException{
     TestXml t = new TestXml();
     t.readXml() ;
   } 
 public void readXml () throws ParserConfigurationException{
    File fXmlFile = new File("D:/formdata.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("record");

    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            System.out.println("Item No : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("item_no").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Description : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("price : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("base qty : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("base_qty").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Var qty : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("var_qty").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Base price : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("base_price_").item(0).getTextContent());                

        }}}}
```

and you will have this result

```
Root element :records
----------------------------

Current Element :record
Item No : 1.0
Description : Hack off tiles and make good walls
price : 100
base qty : 50
Var qty : 20
Base price : 5000

Current Element :record
Item No : 1.03
Description : Test
price : 45
base qty : 100
Var qty : 4500
Base price : 0
```

Comment: I try this but output is same

Comment: I tried with your new xml and it's working. Can you try with the java code I posted and show the result.

Comment: yes I tried your code.Its give following output.
  
Root element :_data399173_eff_sor
----------------------------
Current Element :record
Item No : 1.0
Description : Hack off tiles and make good walls 
price : 100
base qty : 50
Var qty : 20
Base price : 5000
Item No : 1.01
Description : Break up floor in area of shower ( screed or timbe
price : 4
base qty : 1000
Var qty : 0
Base price : 4000

Comment: You are trying with another xml file, please try to validate it before.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your XML is valid -- you're only allowed to have one root element in XML.

So when you do:

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("record");
```

You're only going to get one element. which is that first `<record>...</record>`

In order to fix this, you'll need to wrap all of your `<record>` tags in some sort of a root element like this:

```
<root>
  <record>
    <id>1</id>
  </record>
  <record>
    <id>2</id>
  </record>
  ...
</root>
```

and you'll have to say:

```
NodeList nList = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("record");
```

Comment: No.NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("record") means its will handle only record elements

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in the loop.

```
Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
NodeList list = nNode.getChildNodes();
list.item(0).getTextContent();
```