# How can I configure the XML parser to parse 0x00 as null?

Tags: java, string, byte

I am looking to write a method where the input is an string representation of the xml. Below is the example:

```
<input>
  <name>John</name>
  <some_field>0x00</some_field>
</input>
```

Now, I need to convert this input string to something like:

```
John|NULL
```

Is this possible?

Comment: “How can I configure the XML parser…” What parser?

Comment: [XY] problem. You're assuming the parser can do it and assuming there is a configuration step for it when all you need is a *post* parse conversion. Even an XSLT. And NB "NULL" is n the same thing as `null`.

Answer (score 0):

1 first you must parse it:
see this:
[DOM XML Parser Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396834/dom-xml-parser-example)

2 when you get the value: 0x00, you can test it and convert it to NULL

```
if (value.contentEquals("0x00"))
   { 
   value="NULL";
   // or do what you want
   }
```