# How can i import some information result in website to my program

Tags: java, whois

I'm working on a project (java) that search for whois information for websites, so I started searching for a good websites that provides information about whois lookup, it could be easy for me if I find xml service.

[This](http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://louisville.edu) is the 
the site that provides the information I want to get all the result to my program .

Somone have an idea ?

Comment: you have the URL: load it and parse the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first step: to load

```
InputStream in = new URL("http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://louisville.edu").openStream(); 
String content=IOUtils.toString(in);
in.close();
```

Second step: parse XML: use DOM, read some tutorial

for example: [DOM XML Parser Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396834/dom-xml-parser-example)